# Yii set user for every action in controller

Tags: yii, controller, set, action

i try to set user for every action in controller.

I have acces rules,

and i was set 2 diferent menu for admin and quest.

But I have one action which is not in any menu.

Default user for actions in yii is quest, so if I don't mentioned action in menu for admin, user for that action will be quest.

I don't want to mentioned that action in menu (layout) but i want to user for that action be admin.
In theory I want to set user for every individual action.

```
public function actionTest()
    {
        !Yii::app()->user->isGuest;
        ...
    }
```

Something similar this but this is not work.

MORE CODE:::

I have controller TestController

I have layout main.php

I have login form, and action logout.

So next:

My controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function accessRules()
            {
                    return array(

                        array('allow',
                                    'actions'=>array('login'),
                                    'users'=>array('*'),
                            ),
                        array('allow',
                                    'actions'=>array('test1','test2','logout','test3'),
                                    'users'=>array('@'),
                            ),

                    );
            }

public function actionLogin()
        {
            $this->render('login');
        }
public function actionTest1()
            {
                $this->render('test1');
            }
public function actionTest2()
            {
                $this->render('test2');
            }
public function actionTest3()
                {
                    $this->render('test3');
                }
public function actionLogout()
            {
               ...
            }

}
```

In layout main.php i have criteria for menu:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            {
                $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
                'items'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                        'items'=>array(
                            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/test/login')),
                        ),
                    ),
    ),
));
            }

    else
    {
         $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
                'items'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                        'items'=>array(
                            array('label'=>'Test1', 'url'=>array('/test/test1')),
                            array('label'=>'Test2', 'url'=>array('/test/test2')),
                            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/test/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                        ),
                    ),
    ),
));
    }
```

Like you can see I did not set test3 in 'else' but in test 2 I set redirect to test3 and after login test1 and test2 user will not be quest but test3 will because that is default.
In this situation it is not syntax error.

Comment: post some more code ? tell me what you tried ? what error comes ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by 'but this not work'? Is the user always a guest, or is the user always logged in? Something else?